# TransferFrom failed in Router pancakeswap v2

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to use the "swapExactTokensForTokens" function from the pancakeswap Router contract on the testnet.

The pair that I am trying to use is the WBNB / ETH.

I already approved the amount in the WBNB contract. I also use the function "getAmountsOut"
But I always get the same error:
Fail with error 'TransferHelper :: transferFrom: transferFrom failed'

Router Address: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3#readContract

WBNB Address: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd

ETH Address: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x8babbb98678facc7342735486c851abd7a0d17ca

Transaction detail: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x23b9c4d80e443766d0fe2c33b7f398b0b639f735af06f7488bd6e56d68414014

Any help is welcome, thank you very much

Comment: does the token you are trying to swap *out* of take a transfer fee? if so use the [router V2 ](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xd99d1c33f9fc3444f8101754abc46c52416550d1#code)implementation's function `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`